# How to get value inside a label and use it as condition in SQL where clause?

Tags: c#, wpf

Below are my codes, I have tried the ToString() but it will prompt out error upon running the codes. I want to use the "newName" as my condition to display out what I needed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void onFoodLoad() {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn);
        SqlCommand cmd;
        String connStr;
        string newName = name.Content.ToString();

        try {
            conn.Open();
            //problem here
            connStr = "Select Ingredients, Directions From Food where FoodName = @newFoodName";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(connStr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nnewFoodName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@newFoodName"].Value = newName;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                //name.Content = reader["FoodName"];
                ingredient.Content = reader["Ingredients"];
                direction.Content = "Directions "+ reader["Directions"];
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: can you add your wpf code please

Comment: done...this is all my relevant code for this segment.

Answer (score 0):

Change `connStr` to something like:

```
connStr = "Select Ingredients, Directions From Food where FoodName = @NewFoodName";
```

And add:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewFoodName", newName);
```

after creating the `SqlCommand`.

Kind of a side thing, but you should definitely wrap your `Sql*` creation in a `using` block so that it gets properly disposed after you're done with it, unless of course you are properly disposing of it yourself.

Comment: after I have done according to your codes, the following error occur on the "string newName = name.Content.ToString();" upon running the program. It says "NullReferenceException was unhandled".

Comment: What type of WPF control is `name`?

Comment: I'd guess that `name`'s `Content` is null. You should step through your code with breakpoints (making sure that `name` has a value) and seeing the state of the variables in the method you pasted.

Comment: thanks problem solved. It is because of the sequence of the codes. I should make the onFoodLoad() on the last line.